# azure subscription info

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-packaging

I am a newbie to web development

I would like to host my site in azure.

There are so many subscriptions plans.

So which subscription is reasonably good and give me price details of that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Azure pricing and options, not about programming

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure has few types of hosting. For a website you might want to look at the following -

1. Web Sites - *You can host right away without modification of your existing project.*
2. Cloud Services - *I used this, but it requires changes such as Caching.*

[Here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=web) is the calculator based on your need.

***FYI:*** Rule of thumb is you need a least two instances in Production to minimize the downtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a newbie , I would strongly suggest using azure websites for now, and you can always move to a custom solution using webroles/caching Etc later if you feel it doesn't cater all your needs..

Azure websites pricing can be obtained from here :
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/

Again on what parameters would you choose the right package, you are the best judge for that since you know what traffic are you expecting and how much memory etc you need